# How to edit a folder name in storage folder in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-storage

I am creating a folder for my project in "Laravel" and saves all files inside a folder the same-named as the slug of the project. Whenever I edit my title my slug edited too. So I want my slug folder name to be updated with containing my assets inside the folder

Example:

Project Creation:

Title: My first test project
Slug: my-first-test-project (auto generated from title)

Directory Name: my-first-test-project (same as slug name)

Project Update:

Title: My updated first project
Slug: my-updated-first-project

Directory Name: my-updated-first-project (directory files should remain unchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
Storage::moveDirectory(string $from, string $to, bool $overwrite = false)
```

Documentation: [File Storage \ Directories](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#directories)

Comment: In Laravel 9 it is changed into Storage::move($from, $to): bool;